# Bootstrap based spring application not working offline

Tags: spring, bootstrap-4, mime-types

I downloaded a bootstrap template from internet. And I added that template to my spring application. It's working fine with internet, but my application not loading offline.
I added MIME tags in my web.xml

```
   <!-- web fonts -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>otf</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-opentype</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>      
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>ttf</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>      
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>woff</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>svg</extension>  
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
```

Even though its not working.
I am using tomcat9 server.
Anyone help me how my application load offline ?
Thanks in advance.